# Multiple Rates Limits on NGINX

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

I would like to assign multiple rate limits on NGINX :

- By default, all customers are limited to 1 request per second.
- All whitelisted IPs are limited to 4 requests per second.
- All customers reaching URL http[s]://urlpath.domain.com/**sms** are limited to 6 requests per second.
- All customers reaching URL http[s]://urlpath.domain.com/**sms-backup** are limited to 10 requests per second.

It seems that I'm limited to 1 request per second, even if I'm using a whitelisted IP and / or using sms or sms-backup.

Any idea please ?

My nginx.conf :

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout 2;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    server_tokens off;
    gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    geo $whitelisted_ips {
        default 1;
        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 4;
    }

   map $whitelisted_ips $limited_ip_key4 {
        0 '';
        1 '';
        2 '';
        3 '';
        4 $binary_remote_addr;
   }

    map $whitelisted_ips $limited_ip_key1 {
        0 '';
        1 $binary_remote_addr;
        2 '';
        3 '';
        4 '';
    }

    map $request_uri $is_sms {
        ~^/sms  1;
        default 0;
    }

    map $request_uri $is_infobip {
        ~^/sms-backup  1;
        default 0;
    }

    map $is_sms $sms_key {
        1 $binary_remote_addr;
    }

    map $is_infobip $infobip_key {
        1 $binary_remote_addr;
    }

    limit_req_zone $limited_ip_key4 zone=zone4:10m rate=4r/s;
    limit_req_zone $limited_ip_key1 zone=zone1:10m rate=1r/s;
    limit_req_zone $sms_key zone=limitsms:10m rate=6r/s;
    limit_req_zone $infobip_key zone=limitinfobip:10m rate=100r/s;

}
```

Here is my sites-enabled/default.conf :

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        limit_req zone=zone4 burst=4;
        limit_req zone=zone1 burst=1;
        limit_req zone=limitsms burst=6;
        limit_req zone=limitinfobip burst=100;
        limit_req_status 429;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution. To help people who might be interested :

nginx.conf :

```
http {
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
    real_ip_recursive on;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    # Zones Definitions for API Limitations
    # Limitation API for unknown users
    limit_req_zone $unknown_customer zone=users_1:10m rate=1r/s;
    # --------------------------------------------------------
    # Limitation API for whitelisted users
    limit_req_zone $customer_limited_group_1 zone=users_4:10m rate=4r/s;
    # --------------------------------------------------------
    # Limitation API for SMS users
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=users_sms:10m rate=6r/s;
    # --------------------------------------------------------
    # Limitation API for SMS-Backup users
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=users_sms-backup:10m rate=10r/s;
    # --------------------------------------------------------
    # Limitation API for whitelisted users
    map $remote_addr $unknown_customer {
            xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   '';
            default                 $binary_remote_addr;
    }
    map $remote_addr $customer_limited_group_1 {
            xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    1;
    }
    # --------------------------------------------------------

}
```

website :

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        # Limitation API for unknown users
        limit_req zone=users_1 burst=1;
        # --------------------------------------------------------
        # Limitation API for whitelisted users
        limit_req zone=users_4 burst=4;
        # ------------------------------------------------------------
        limit_req_status 429;
    }

    # Limitation API for SMS users
    location ~ ^/v1/sms(/|$) {
        limit_req zone=users_sms burst=6;
        limit_req_status 429;
    }
    # ------------------------------------------------------------
    # Limitation API for SMS-Backup
    location ~ ^/v1/sms-backup {
        limit_req zone=users_sms-backup burst=10;
        limit_req_status 429;
    }
    # ------------------------------------------------------------
    
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

Cheers